# How to find out if this is the last iteration in AWS Step Functions map task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have a Map state which iterates my array. Inside the map state, there is a Lambda task and a Wait task. The Wait task is waiting much time, and I need to wait only between iterations. So I would like to skip waiting if this is the last iteration because there is no need for it.

**Every time the items are different and their amount is different.**

However, the Map context has only **$$.Map.Item.Index** and **$$.Map.Item.Value** variables. I couldn't find any mention of any variable with the total amount of steps for example.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want to identify the "last iteration".  What do you mean by that? Given Map state items [A, B, C], what is the last iteration?  Is it "C", the last element in the items array?  Or perhaps "B", if "A" and "C" have finished first?

Comment: @fedonev I have a limited concurrency, so they go one by one. So that is C. But actually, that does not matter which is the sequence. I need to know that there is no more so this is definitely the last one - no matter A, B or C it is.

Comment: I ask because the having each iteration introspect whether it is "C" (the last array item) is a determinate and easy problem.  Introspecting whether a concurrent iteration is the last one still running is an indeterminate and hard problem.

Comment: @fedonev yes, that is the issue that every time the items are different and their amount is different.

Comment: What's your definition of done?  For _N_ items in a Map State (where _N_ is not known in advance), exit the State ASAP after _N-1_ items (all but the "last iteration") have finished?

Comment: @fedonev no, every iteration in Map consists of 2 steps - Lambda and Wait. Given A, B, C items to Map state, now I have: [A->Wait, B->Wait, C->Wait]. I need to skip the last Wait e.g. [A->Wait, B->Wait, C]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding:  Each execution has an arbitrary number of Map items that should run serially (i.e. `MaxConcurrency:1`). You want no delay after the last item.  For instance, an execution with 4 items `[A, B, C, D]` should run in the following order:  `Lambda(A), Wait, Lambda(B), Wait, Lambda(C), Wait, Lambda(D)`.  A single-item execution `[A]` should run `Lambda(A)` only.

Here is one way to do it:

[**Update - late 2022:**  Using the new `ArrayLength` and `MathAdd` [intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html) we can calculate the last item index without a lambda - see `"LastItemIndex.$"` below]

1. <del>Insert a Lambda Task before the Map State.  The Lambda counts the items and outputs the last item's index to `$.itemsCounter.lastItemIndex`.</del>
2. Add the last item and the item index to the Map iterations' payloads with [Parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html#amazon-states-language-map-state-output) on the Map State:

```json
// add to the Map State definition - overrides what each iteration receives
"Parameters": {
  "Index.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
  "Data.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",  // by default, each iteration just gets this
  "LastItemIndex.$": "States.MathAdd(States.ArrayLength($$.Execution.Input.Items), -1)", // 3 for {"Items": [A,B,C,D]}
},
```

3. Add a `ShouldWait?` Choice State inside the Map between the Lambda Task and Wait State.  Proceed to Wait unless `$.Index` equals `$.LastItemIndex`.

Comment: thanks, sounds reasonable, I'll give it a try and post the result!